# Filter dataframe based on the quantile per group of values

Tags: pandas, group-by, quantile

Let's suppose that I have a dataframe like that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A', 'A', 'B','B'], 'col2':[2, 4, 6, 3, 4]})
```

I want to keep from it only the rows which have values at `col2` which are less than the x-th quantile of the values for each of the groups of values of `col1` separately.

For example for the 60-th percentile then the dataframe should look like that:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     2
1    A     4
2    B     3
```

How can I do this efficiently in `pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have `transform` with `quantile`

```
df[df.col2.lt(df.groupby('col1').col2.transform(lambda x : x.quantile(0.6)))]
  col1  col2
0    A     2
1    A     4
3    B     3
```